# Shrinking <img> when <p> grows and keeping aspect ratio with flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a static height container.

Inside I have one `div` element with an `img` element inside.

Below that there is a `p` tag which is populated dynamically with text.

When the text is longer and the `p` tag becomes larger I want the image above to shrink to make room inside the container.

I have been trying to do this with `flex` and `flex-shrink`. This is what I've got:

http://codepen.io/niper1/pen/yaBxvx

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#main div {
  flex-shrink: 3;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
p {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/">
  </div>
  <p>Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text N</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `img` tag is not shrinking to make enough space. Is this possible to do with flex-box or am I going to have to look for a different route?

Answer (score 2):

A flex item, by default, cannot be smaller than the length of its content.

The initial size of a flex item is `min-height: auto` and `min-width: auto`.

Regardless of `flex-shrink`, your flex item will not be smaller than your image, unless you override the default with `min-height: 0`. (It would be `min-width: 0`, if your container were row-direction.)

Also, not all browsers recognize a parent's flex height as a reference for a child element's percentage height. So it's important to specify a `height` or `flex-basis` on the parent of the image.

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#main div {
  flex: 1 1 100%;              /* 1 */
  min-height: 0;               /* 2 */
}

img {
  height: auto;                /* 3 */
  width: 100%;                 /* 3 */
}

p {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-height: 0;               /* 2 */
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/">
  </div>
  <p>Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text Test text N</p>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)
2. [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
3. adjusted original code block

Comment: Thank you for your reply, setting min-height: 0; helped so now it wont flow outside the container. However with this solution the img is not contained by the div (the img flows outside the div).

Comment: Not seeing that behavior here. The image is contained (in Chrome, at least). Maybe consider making the div also a flex container.